# How to change the colour of webpack compilation output?

Tags: webstorm

The text colour in the **Run** window during a webpack complition appears mainly in red. How can this be changed so that it is white (or another colour) and only red when there are errors?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't.
Webpack writes compilation progress to stderr stream. And it's highlighted according to Error output preferences (`Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors`, `Console/Error output`, default is red) in WebStorm. ANSI colors are not interpreted there ([IDEA-137769](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137769))